# UINavigationControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller in iOS7

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7

One of my apps refuses to launch and am getting this exception in iOS7.  The wording in the excpetion looks like a tantrum thrown by an engineer, especially the exclamation point.  The code runs fine in iOS 5/6 and has no warnings associated with it.  There is neither a warning in xcode 5.  Including an abbreviated code slice.  The reason I have done this is creating my own custom tabbar, which controls the entire navigation of the app.

```
2013-06-10 22:24:52.862 [3375:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UINavigationControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller!'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x2c56028 0x29da902 0x1009873 0x2cd22fd 0x2cd2232 0x2c4fae5 0x1009716 0x100943f 0x1008ec5 0x9905 0xef05f9 0xef0daa 0xef21dc 0xf07c6c 0xf081d9 0xef3e55 0x3d6ace2 0x3d6a7ed 0x2bd18d5 0x2bd160a 0x2bfc032 0x2bfb59f 0x2bfb3eb 0xef1960 0xef3b6b 0x8e2d 0x8d95)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Code:

```
UIViewController *homeController, *contactController, *procedureController, *wizardController, *teamController, *askController;

homeController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *homeNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeController];

wizardController = [[ProcedureWizardController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProcedureWizardController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *wizardNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:wizardController];

askController = [[AskViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AskViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *askNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:askController];

teamController = [[TeamViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TeamViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *teamNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:teamController];

procedureController = [[ProcedureViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProcedureViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *procNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:procedureController];


contactController = [[ContactViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *contactNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contactController];

viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeNavController, wizardNavController, askNavController, teamNavController, procNavController, contactNavController, nil];

navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];;

navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:viewControllers];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is correct.  Apple obviously fixed an issue in iOS7 that was not uncovered in 4,5 and 6.

Don't nest UINavigationControllers.

Comment: FYI if you are using a UISplitViewController then UINavigationController is modified internally to allow nesting. The reason for this is to support collapsing to compact where the detail navigation controller is pushed onto the master navigation controller.